# Regex / SublimeText : replace string if surrounded by items to NOT replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have many, many string such as:

```
Hello Dear World ! ! !
How are you Going ? ! . . .
```

I want to replace the space if only between words by tabs. Which regex to use ?

---

I tried :

```
FIND:    \w\s\w
REPLACE: \w\t\w
```

But that replace the surrounding words by "\w".

```
Hellw:weaw:world ! ! !
How:wrw:wow:woing ? ! . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find: (\w+)\s(\w+)
Replace: $1\t$2

() does match a subpattern which can be referenced by $1 for the first match and $n for the n-th match. \w+ is required to match the whole word instead of the first character only

Comment: Awesome. :)
Is this specific to SublimeText 2 or works for most text editors ?